# How to navigate to a section of a page

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a landing page with links.
How can I direct user to a section of a different page?

Main Page:

```
<a href="/sample">Sushi</a>
<a href="/sample">BBQ</a>
```

Sample Page:

```
<div id='sushi'></div>
<div id='bbq'></div>
```

Clicking on "Sushi" or "BBQ" in the Main Page should navigate the user to the div with id `sushi` or `bbq` (respectively) of the page `sample`.

Is it possible without JQuery?
I do not mind using JQuery but a simpler solution using html would work too.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use HTML's [anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html):

Main Page:

```
<a href="sample.html#sushi">Sushi</a>
<a href="sample.html#bbq">BBQ</a>
```

Sample Page:

```
<div id='sushi'><a name='sushi'></a></div>
<div id='bbq'><a name='bbq'></a></div>
```

Comment: using name in Anchor gives a warning: Deprecated HTML attribute. I think referring to the ID of your target element is a safer method to do this. Like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994391/10703628

Answer (score 22):

Wrap your div with

```
<a name="sushi">
  <div id="sushi">
  </div>
</a>
```

and link to it by

```
<a href="#sushi">Sushi</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use anchors.

Main Page:

```
<a href="/sample#sushi">Sushi</a>
<a href="/sample#bBQ">BBQ</a>
```

Sample Page:

```
<div id='sushi'><a name="sushi"></a></div>
<div id='bbq'><a name="bbq"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use hypertext reference and the ID tag,

## Target Text Title

Some paragraph text

Target Text

```
<h1><a href="#target">Target Text Title</a></h1>
<p id="target">Target Text</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an call thru section, it works

```
<div id="content">
     <section id="home">
               ...
     </section>
```

Call the above the thru

```
 <a href="#home">page1</a>
```

Scrolling needs jquery paste this.. on above to ending body closing tag..

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                  $('html,body').animate({
                      scrollTop: target.offset().top
                  }, 1000);
                  return false;
              }
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Main page

```
<a href="/sample.htm#page1">page1</a>
<a href="/sample.htm#page2">page2</a>
```

sample pages

```
<div id='page1'><a name="page1"></a></div>
<div id='page2'><a name="page2"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solutions:

```
$("body").scrollspy({ target: ".target", offset: fix_header_height });

$(".target").click(function() {
 $("body").animate(
  {
   scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - fix_header_height
  },
  500
 );
 return;
});
```