# HTML Syntax Errors

Tags: html

well it's a closed html because it's a 2 part thing.. here is the full code. i have been struggling with this assignment for over a week now.. if you could help me out i would really appreciate it. when i try to validate the below the errors i get are : ""Error: Stray start tag a.
From line 39, column 1; to line 39, column 22
↩↩↩Learn 
Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
From line 39, column 1; to line 39, column 22
↩↩↩Learn ""

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
  table
  {
     border-style: solid;
  }

  td
  {
     border-style: solid; 
     border-color: #FF66FF;
     padding: 10px;
   }
</style>
<title>
Ian Morgan Kettell
</title>


<body>
<h1>Ian's Hobbies! </h1>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Camping</td>
  <td>Hiking</td>
  <td>Cycling</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fishing</td>
  <td>Kayaking</td>
  <td>Skiing</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>

<a href="movies.html">Learn about Ian's Favorite Actors and Movies!</a>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>
Ian Morgan Kettell
</title>
<h3>
My Favorite Movies
</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        Promised Land
    </li>
    <li>
        Flight
    </li>
    <li>
        Taken
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    The movies I chose were Promised Land starring Matt Damon, Flight starring Denzel Washington, and Taken starring Liam Neeson. Even though I have an endless
    list of favorite movies these are by far my top 3. I like them because I like movies I can learn things from. For instance; Promised Land is a film about
    oil companies fighting to buy land from farmers to frack the land to find oil. It shows both sides of the process of how they convince people and I found
    it extremely interesting.
</p>
<h3>
    My Favorite Actors
</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        Matt Damon
    </li>
    <li>
        Denzel Washington
    </li>
    <li>
        Liam Neeson
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    If I had to choose my favorite actors my top 3 would be Matt Damon, Denzel Washington, and Liam Neeson. I think Denzel Washington is my favorite actor of
    all time. He has been an actor since the year 1981 when he made his debut apperance in the comedy A Carbon Copy.He is best known for Philadelphia Man, Man
    on Fire, The Book Of Eli, American Gangster, and Flight.In recent years he has starred in action movies. Some of my favorite movies he's in are Inside Man,
    Out of Time and The Book Of Eli, these are all kind of action dramas.
</p>
</html>
```

Comment: This contains absolutely no code -- What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Your `<title>` and `<meta>` elements needs to be in a `<head>` tag. Probably the `<style>` tag should be in there too. Also, you have TWO `</html>`'s but no begin tag.

Comment: How are you in a class that requires validation without learning how to write a simple HTML page?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish in-page navigation like this?jsfiddle.net/cowdd/7stn6nbh

Comment: @ArleighHix "In-page" navigation is not done by pushing content way down the page. That's not a "thing" - that's a hack.  Something like what you are showing would be done with JavaScript and CSS's `display` property.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Correct, but a far better hack than what he started with

Comment: @ArleighHix But, the OP isn't trying to accomplish what you are showing anyway. He is simply navigating to another page, which he did correctly. How is your incorrect example supposed to be better than his actual link?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was asking the OP

Comment: @ArleighHix And, I'm pointing out that the question was not even needed in the first place since the hyperlink makes it clear what the intention was.

Comment: btw it is a thing https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1 (that very page uses this method and explains it) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172717/how-to-navigate-to-a-section-of-a-page

Answer (score 2):

Your code is an absolute mess and doesn't follow the proper document structure for an HTML file, which should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

You had multiple `<html>` tags and tags in the wrong place with content that should not have been in them. For example, your `<meta>` tag was inside of your `<style>` element. Other issues I see: you have an `<h1>` and then jump to `<h3>`. Where's the `<h2>`?

So, your file would need to be re-worked to be like this (which does validate):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Ian Morgan Kettell</title>
         <style>
             table {
               border-style: solid;
             }
    
             td {
              border-style: solid; 
              border-color: #FF66FF;
              padding: 10px;
             }
         </style>
       </head>
       <body>
         <h1>Ian's Hobbies! </h1>
         <table>
           <tr>
            <td>Camping</td>
            <td>Hiking</td>
            <td>Cycling</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Fishing</td>
            <td>Kayaking</td>
            <td>Skiing</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
   
        <a href="movies.html">Learn about Ian's Favorite Actors and Movies!</a>
       <h2>My Favorite Movies</h2>
       <ul>
        <li>Promised Land</li>
        <li>Flight</li>
        <li>Taken</li>
       </ul>
      <p>
        The movies I chose were Promised Land starring Matt Damon, Flight
        starring Denzel Washington, and Taken starring Liam Neeson. Even though
        I have an endless list of favorite movies these are by far my top 3. I 
        like them because I like movies I can learn things from. For instance; 
        Promised Land is a film about oil companies fighting to buy land from 
        farmers to frack the land to find oil. It shows both sides of the 
        process of how they convince people and I found it extremely interesting.
     </p>
     <h2>My Favorite Actors</h2>
     <ul>
        <li>Matt Damon</li>
        <li>Denzel Washington</li>
        <li>Liam Neeson</li>
     </ul>
     <p>
        If I had to choose my favorite actors my top 3 would be Matt Damon, 
        Denzel Washington, and Liam Neeson. I think Denzel Washington is my 
        favorite actor of all time. He has been an actor since the year 1981 
        when he made his debut apperance in the comedy A Carbon Copy.He is best 
        known for Philadelphia Man, Man on Fire, The Book Of Eli, American 
        Gangster, and Flight.In recent years he has starred in action movies. 
        Some of my favorite movies he's in are Inside Man, Out of Time and The 
        Book Of Eli, these are all kind of action dramas.
     </p>
    </html>
```

Comment: Someone seems to be voting down everybody, so I've upvoted everybody (except myself, I should be tied with you)

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to validate online a `HTML` DOM structure:

You code has the following issues:

```
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 39, column 1)
Discarding Unexpected <html> (At line 40, column 2)
<meta> Lacks "content" Attribute (At line 41, column 1)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 41, column 1)
<meta> Isn't Allowed In <body> Elements (At line 41, column 1)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 43, column 2)
<title> Isn't Allowed In <body> Elements (At line 43, column 2)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 46, column 2)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 49, column 1)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 60, column 1)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 66, column 1)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 69, column 1)
Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 80, column 1)
Discarding Unexpected </html> (At line 86, column -3)
```

You can use several online HTML validator to check this like W3C Markup [Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) or other tools like [this one.](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html)

So in your specific case, you have a closing `html` tag on line 39, that is the first error we can see and the classic

`Content Occurs After End Of Body (At line 39, column 1)`

and so on.
As **W3C** validator points out, this first error is marked as `FATAL`, no way to parse the structure over:

```
Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.
```

Comment: The validator results clearly shows the syntax errors in the posted code, line by line, error by error, there is nothing more to be added to this actually.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the order and structure of the tags to make it look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta ...>
    <style type="text/css">
    ...
    </style>
    <title>...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
</table>
```

Try fillling in the dots yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard markup of a valid webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

All of the tags in the above HTML may only appear **ONE** time in the file, and in this arrangement.

Comment: `html` and `head` can actually be omitted in HTML5 (although, I don't recommend it) and the document will still be considered valid.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Valid by what standard? Certainly not by W3C, which is the validator the OP is using.

Comment: Absolutely by the W3C. Take your code and remove the `html` and `head` tags and run it through the validator.w3.org page. It will validate. The HTML5 spec. has nearly 400 pages devoted to how a client should deal with documents that omit various elements and because of this, many elements that in the past were required are now optional.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I have updated my answer. For those who have downvoted just because of the HTML5 caveat, they may remove it.

Comment: @4castle oops commented in the wrong place. btw it is there, its just hidden by the jsFiddle messages, saying they do not need to be there for the fiddle to work, but I left everything there as it should be for a complete example.

Answer (score -1):

You had a lot of errors with this document:

1. You forgot to put  right after `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. You need to put your styles and titles in between `<head></head>` tags
3. You have 2 titles in your doc when you only need one.
4. You have 2 closing `</html>` tags when you need one. And it should be at the bottom only

Here's your code all cleaned up. You shouldn't get any errors now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-style: solid;
        }
    
        td {
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #FF66FF;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>
        Ian Morgan Kettell
    </title>
</head>



<body>
<h1>Ian's Hobbies! </h1>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Camping</td>
  <td>Hiking</td>
  <td>Cycling</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fishing</td>
  <td>Kayaking</td>
  <td>Skiing</td>
</tr>
</table>



<a href="movies.html">Learn about Ian's Favorite Actors and Movies!</a>



<h2>
My Favorite Movies
</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        Promised Land
    </li>
    <li>
        Flight
    </li>
    <li>
        Taken
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    The movies I chose were Promised Land starring Matt Damon, Flight starring Denzel Washington, and Taken starring Liam Neeson. Even though I have an endless
    list of favorite movies these are by far my top 3. I like them because I like movies I can learn things from. For instance; Promised Land is a film about
    oil companies fighting to buy land from farmers to frack the land to find oil. It shows both sides of the process of how they convince people and I found
    it extremely interesting.
</p>
<h2>
    My Favorite Actors
</h2>
<ul>
    <li>
        Matt Damon
    </li>
    <li>
        Denzel Washington
    </li>
    <li>
        Liam Neeson
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    If I had to choose my favorite actors my top 3 would be Matt Damon, Denzel Washington, and Liam Neeson. I think Denzel Washington is my favorite actor of
    all time. He has been an actor since the year 1981 when he made his debut apperance in the comedy A Carbon Copy.He is best known for Philadelphia Man, Man
    on Fire, The Book Of Eli, American Gangster, and Flight.In recent years he has starred in action movies. Some of my favorite movies he's in are Inside Man,
    Out of Time and The Book Of Eli, these are all kind of action dramas.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've still got the `meta` tag inside the `style` block and you have still got `h3` coming after `h1`.

Comment: Fixed the meta tag in the edit. Not sure what you mean by the h3 tag though.

Comment: @Shepard Heading elements (h1...h6) are meant to convey the document outline structure - - they mean that a section is beginning. You don't go from heading 1 to heading 3 without having a heading 2 in between them.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Although I understand it's good structure, I think that in this case OP was just going for a smaller font size so I felt no need to change it. But I changed it just for you, sweety. ;)

Comment: @Shepard Font sizes should not be set with HTML. That is what CSS is for. The heading elements are semantic elements that are used to denote section structure in a document.