# HTML/CSS. goto a class?

Tags: html, css

in HTML you have the possibility, with the tag TOP, to go on the top on the page directly. For this reason I thought that maybe there is also the possibility to click a link in my webpage and goto directly to a specific class (only html/csss)... Is it possible or not?

Comment: You can't, but maybe anchors are enough - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172717/how-to-navigate-to-a-section-of-a-page

Answer (score 18):

Not to a specific class, becuase there can be many elements with the same classname, but with an ID it's possible.

```
<!-- Somehwere on your page -->
<span id="boookmark1"></span>

<!-- Somewhere else on your page -->
<a href="#bookmark1">Go to bookmark1</a>
```

Comment: @LUca - I am happy to help. If this solved your problem, please click the check-mark to accept the answer.