# Href Navigation to Div Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

In my html page there are few div tags and each of them is having `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`. Usually we use href for navigation from 1 page to other page

And I could like to navigate from one div tag to another div tage from using
href. Can any one help me how can I do it.

Comment: Give the `id` of the `div` you want to navigate to in the `href`

Comment: [Take a look at here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172717/how-to-navigate-to-a-section-of-a-page). Please always do your research first before posting. You might find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on `Jump` will take you to `div#anchor1`

```
<a href="#anchor1">Jump</a>
<div id="anchor1">Your content goes here</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1pwo1gqb/1/

Answer (score 1):

All you have to use id and attach it to the a tag like this

```css
.container{
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.nav{
  position: fixed;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#s1">section 1</a>
  <a href="#s2">section 2</a>
  <a href="#s3">section 3</a>
  <a href="#s4">section 4</a>
  <a href="#s5">section 5</a>
  <a href="#s6">section 6</a>
 </div>
<div class="container" id="s1">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="s2">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="s3">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="s4">
  <h1>Section 4</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="s5">
  <h1>Section 5</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="s6">
  <h1>Section 6</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @sandeep Nayak have explained,

```
 <div id="div1"> some data <a href="#div2">Go to div 2</a> </div>
 <div id="div2"> some data <a href="#div1">Go to div 1</a> </div>
```