# Html href to a specific place in another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I put an href tag with link to a specific h1 tag in another page?
This is what I tried...

```
<a href="page2.html/subject 2">Move to page 2, section 1</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate to a section of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172717/how-to-navigate-to-a-section-of-a-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:-

```
<div id="anchor-name"> <h1>Heading goes here </h1></div>
```

and refer to it later with

```
<a href="http://server/page.html#anchor-name">Link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to give unique id to h1 tag on page2.

```
<a href="page2.html/subject 2#firstH1">Move to page 2, section 1</a>
```

Where #firstH1 is the id given to h1

Answer (score 0):

Add page link to **href** with additional reference to the id of the specific div containing the heading(h1).

```
<a href="page2.html#mydiv"> Click to move to next page heading </a>
```

Here, **page2.html** is the link to next page and **mydiv** is the id of the div in which h1 is present.

```
<div id="mydiv>
  <h1> My Heading </h1>
</div>
```

P.S: You can use the same approach to scroll to different parts on the same page.

Use **target='_blank'** if you want to open the next page in a new tab.