# React routing on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

I am new to React, and I trying to make a website that has only one page with multiple section. How can I make a navigation bar to send me when I click, for example, on contact link to contact section that is lower in the page. Or when I click 'Services' to go upper in the page(exemple). I don't want code snippets, I just want a starting point. About what shoul I read? I am looking for this thing for a couple of hours but I can't find anything.

Comment: Trying go through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172717/how-to-navigate-to-a-section-of-a-page

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a href="#id">
```

where id is the id of the tag you want to go. For example, you have a div

```
<div id="section1">
```

and another div

```
<div id="section2">
```

you can create two anchor in your navigation bar

```
<a href="#section1"> <a href="#section2">
```

which when clicked scrolls the page to the corresponding section.